# Using cgroups to control memory usage on Linux

Tags: linux, memory-management, process, cgroups

I’m trying to use cgroups to stop programs that actually USE too much memory, while letting them run if they just allocate and don’t actually use lots of memory. However, it doesn’t seem to work; any suggestions?  On a Ubuntu machine, I set up my cgroup as follows[1]:

```
#Changing $USER to a system user running the process
sudo apt-get install cgroup-bin
sudo cgcreate -a $USER -g memory:$USER
echo 100M > /cgroup/memory/$USER/memory.limit_in_bytes

#Running the program using cgroups
cgexec -g memory:$USER program
```

I am using the following program (answering ‘no’ should work, and ‘yes’ should be stopped).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE (long int) 1*1024*1024*1024*sizeof(char)/*1 GB*/

int main(void)
{
  char *str = (char*) malloc(SIZE);
  char *ans = (char*) malloc(100);

  printf("Write random values to memory? (yes/no): ");
  scanf("%s", ans);

  if (strcmp(ans,"yes") == 0) {
    FILE *f = fopen("/dev/urandom","r");
    fread(str,1,SIZE,f);
    printf("Success!!\n");
    fclose(f);
    free(str);
  }
  else {
    printf("Have a good day!\n");
  }

  return(0); 
}
```

[1] https://askubuntu.com/questions/94619/how-to-set-cpu-limit-for-given-process-permanently-cpulimit-and-nice-dont-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You test is returning success as it doesn't check for error. In fact, the fread call failed allocation when your binary hit the memory limit.
You can see that by changing the code to check for error:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE (long int) 1*1024*1024*1024*sizeof(char)/*1 GB*/

int main(void)
{
  char *str = (char*) malloc(SIZE);
  char *ans = (char*) malloc(100);

  printf("Write random values to memory? (yes/no): ");
  scanf("%s", ans);

  if (strcmp(ans,"yes") == 0) {
    FILE *f = fopen("/dev/urandom","r");
    int size = fread(str,1,SIZE,f);
    if (size < SIZE) {
        printf("incomplete read: %d, error %d\n", size, ferror(f));
    } else {
        printf("Success!!\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
    free(str);
  }
  else {
    printf("Have a good day!\n");
  }

  return(0);
}
```

Even cooler is to use a cgroup monitoring utility like [cadvisor](http://github.com/google/cadvisor) You can graphically see your binary hitting the limit. [image: cadvisor]. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Checking for error was the key.  It is also important to disable memory swapping.  I did it by 'swapoff -a'.  I also notice that the memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes is missing.  How did you set/disable memory swapping?

Comment: I had swap turned off globally on my system and memswap was not configured in kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would be a better test program.  It allocates a lot of memory, and if you answer 'y' it will try to USE it.  Just allocating the memory should work, but trying to later actually USE it should trigger the OOM killer.  Be sure to run "swapoff" first.  Instead of reading from /dev/urandom (which takes a while), this just writes % 256 to each byte, which should be faster.  I haven't tried to test this with cgroups.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MiB 1024*1024

#define CHUNK_SIZE (100 * MiB)
#define CHUNKS 100000

void overwrite(char *s, size_t size) {
  for (; size > 0; s++, size--)
    *s = (char) (size % 256); // Vary what's written to prevent optimizations
}

int main() {
  char *chunk[CHUNKS];
  int i;
  int numchunks;
  int result;

  printf("Allocating many memory chunks.\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  for (i = 0; i<CHUNKS; i++) {
    chunk[i] = malloc(CHUNK_SIZE);
    if (!chunk[i]) {
      i--;
      printf("Cannot allocate any more\n");
    }
  }
  numchunks = i;

  printf("Should values be written to memory?\n");
  result = getchar();
  if (result == 'y' || result == 'Y') {
    printf("\nWriting chunks of size %d:\n", (unsigned) CHUNK_SIZE);
    fflush(stdout);
    for (i = 0; i<numchunks; i++) {
      printf(" %d", i);
      fflush(stdout);
      overwrite(chunk[i], CHUNK_SIZE);
    }
  }
  printf("Program exiting\n");
  return 0;
}
```